# HTML, Javascript web page auto login

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load an external page and run auto login script. This is what I got so far, but it's not working =( Any help be appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
javascript:(function(){
  window.open ("https://external page address","_self");
  document.getElementById("username").value="my username";
  document.getElementById("password").value="my password";
  document.getElementById("loginbutton").click();
})();
</script>

</head>

<title>Login Page</title>

<body onload="function()">



</body>
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in more detail

Comment: pretty sure you cant do what your trying to do, basicly cos your opening new window so the rest of your commands wont happen

Comment: If you can modify the header of the external page and add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` then only you can access external page content.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this. Web applications cannot talk cross-origin to other web pages inside of a web browser.